# I have a question concerning wash sale rules pertaining to dividend reinvestment

Tags: wash-sale

I would like to sell shares of stock A to offset gains from other holdings this tax year. I had set stock A dividends to be used to acquire more shares of stock A. The last dividend reinvestment occurred on Dec 4, and I acquired x (number of shares). If I sell all my shares of stock A can I take the tax loss on those shares sold minus x (number of shares)? And since shares sold are FIFO can I sell shares of stock A minus x (number of shares) and take the tax loss on all shares of stock A sold?

Comment: Wash sale rules only exist in certain places, and are different from place to place. What's your jurisdiction? Also, are you planning complete disposition of A, or only partial?

Answer (score 0):

In the USA, if you purchase replacement shares within 30 days before or after realizing a loss in a taxable account, it's a wash sale. It doesn't matter what type of account you repurchase the shares.

You will have to calculate a proportionate loss for "X" reinvestment shares and carry that loss forward to 2024.  If you would like to avoid this, sell these shares as well and do not acquire anymore of this stock for 31 days.